# What are the meanings of "enclose" and can it be used instead of "shut" here?

Tags: word-usage

Can "enclose" be used instead of "shut" in this sentence?

> The boy did not obey his parents, so, they decided to enclose him in the house for two days.

Comment: That's not really a metaphor.

Comment: You can find the meanings of *enclose* in [many dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=enclose&ls=a). And while *enclose* is possible in this sentence (meaning *contain*), it is unnatural and I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my AmE ear, **enclose** would not sound correct though from a dictionary perspective you might be convinced to use it.

**To enclose** is **to surround** and **animals** are kept in **enclosures**, but not **people** unless meant in a **derogatory way**.

> The animals **enclosures** at the zoo have been updated.
>   The Bengal tigers are kept **enclosed** in the Tiger House.

Your original use of **shut** would be more correct, but sounds **severe** and **punitive**

> He was **shut in** prison for doing the crime.
>   **Shut-ins** can refer to people with mobility problems.

For a child, **keep** would be better

> They decided to **keep** him indoors for two days for being **naughty**.
>   They **grounded** him for two day by **keeping** him indoors.